# how to move the control from one uiview to another uiview in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I created  a uiview(with two buttons) covers all the screen whenever i click on any one of button i want to transfer my control on previous screen what can i do in iphone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code for navigating from one view to another is as belove :

```
DetailViewController *detailViewController;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailsViewController animated:YES];
```

and for going back :

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

leave comment if have any trouble...
and click on correct sign if its correct...and votes up the answer to help another guys to see it.

Comment: The question asked how to display the previously active view, not how to push a new view.  mihirpmehta's solution is the correct approach to the problem.

Comment: Hi,mattmccomb i know what you are saying but see the title of the question first and then read the whole story. hope you understand from which context i have given this answer...

Answer (score 0):

if you are using NavigationController than for going back to previous view...

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Otherwise

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```